# Python Shared Network, loadFromRemoteSources

Tags: python, networking, clr, python.net

I build my python code with pyarmor + nuitka so i get exe. Sharing this exe with shared network.
But When exe tries to load dll (import clr) it gets

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Failed to load the file 'file: // \\ 192.168.1.251 \ MyFolder\ GameMenu \ Python.Runtime.dll' or its integrated code or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (HRESULT returned exception: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an integrated code from a network location that would cause it to be sandboxed in previous .NET Framework versions. This .NET Framework version does not enable CAS policy by default, so the installation in question can be dangerous. If this installation is not intended to sandbox the integrated code, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. For more information. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569
```

But when i copy all folders to desktop, trying to run my exe, it works fine. The issue is load dll from shared network.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, in my case I copied the files to other pc and I face the same error. The fix that worked for me was properties on the Python.Runtime.dll and check "Unlock".
I know is not the exactly same case but I leave this here in case that helps anyone.